# Bottom camera problem

Tags: ros, tum-ardrone, ardrone-autonomy, tum-simulator, ardrone2.0

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I use gazebo 2.2 with ROS package tum_simulator. This is a package with simulator of quadrotor AR Parrot Drone.

I had thought that bottom camera is not working and only front camera is OK, but I noticed that image from bottom camera don't display ground but sky. (strange)

Please check this screen: http://snag.gy/L5Riw.jpg

This is a world from Gazebo and two windows from rviz. Left image is a view from bottom camera :( and right image is a view from front camera. Black shape near window of the house is quadrotors' model.

Have you ever heard abut this problem? Any ideas?

I notice that when I run this node I got some errors, I hope that this is a reason of problems with camera.

```
Error [SDF.cc:788] Missing element description for [offset]
Error [SDF.cc:788] Missing element description for [drift]
Error [SDF.cc:788] Missing element description for [driftFrequency]
[ INFO] [1415319050.065958118, 659.736000000]: Camera Plugin (ns = /)  <tf_prefix_>, set to ""
[ INFO] [1415319050.244706409, 659.736000000]: Camera Plugin (ns = /)  <tf_prefix_>, set to ""
Error [SDF.cc:788] Missing element description for [accelOffset]
Error [SDF.cc:788] Missing element description for [accelDriftFrequency]
Error [SDF.cc:788] Missing element description for [rateOffset]
Error [SDF.cc:788] Missing element description for [rateDriftFrequency]
Error [SDF.cc:788] Missing element description for [headingOffset]
Error [SDF.cc:788] Missing element description for [headingDriftFrequency]
Error [SDF.cc:788] Missing element description for [driftFrequency]
Error [SDF.cc:788] Missing element description for [driftFrequency]
Error [SDF.cc:788] Missing element description for [offset]
Error [SDF.cc:788] Missing element description for [driftFrequency]
Error [SDF.cc:788] Missing element description for [velocityOffset]
Error [SDF.cc:788] Missing element description for [velocityDriftFrequency]
[ INFO] [1415319050.590175130, 659.736000000]: Using imu information on topic ardrone/imu as source of orientation and angular velocity.
```

Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196959/bottom-camera-problem/) by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2014-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was an issue with the orientation of the bottom camera on a urdf file (@green96 found the issue). You can look [here](https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_simulator/pull/4) for more information.

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2014-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1